# Transforming a list to list of lists using a specific rule

Tags: list-manipulation

Say, we have a list: `l = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}` and a corresponding list: `v = {2,3,2,3,4}`. We want to split `l` into sublists of certain length of consecutive elements of`l` and `v` basically tells us what that length should be. So, in this case, our output would be:

```
{{1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7},{8,9,10},{11,12,13,14}}
```

I have written a function that works:

```
g[l_List] := Module[{split},
split =Table[, {i,1,Length @ l}];
split[[1]] = Table[i,{i,1,First @ l}];
Table[split[[i+1]] = Table[j,{j,Last @ split[[i]] + 1 ,Total @ l[[1;;i+1]]}], 
{i,1,Length@l - 1}];
split
]

g@v
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14}}

But I'm sure this could be done in a nicer, and more importantly, more efficient way. Any hints?

Comment: It might be worth thinking about what happens when `Total@v` does not equal `Length@l`.

Comment: In my case that is always the case, but yeah, it's a valid point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use this built-in

```
 TakeList[l,v]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14}}

the above solution works with version 11.3

If you have an older version try

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop,l,v]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14}}

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!